# Вывод формы через цикл и отправка данных с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, циклы

Добрый день. Есть таблица с выводом множества записей. у каждой строки этой таблицы есть выпадающий список для выбора нужного нам параметра и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку данные попадают в ajax обработчик. Проблема в том что в ajax отправляется только самая первая запись из выпадающего списка, и не важно с какой кнопки нажимать. Вот код на php:

```
foreach ($sql as $data){
    echo '<th><select>';
    foreach ($sql2 as $data2){
        echo '<option id="ProdID" value="'.$data2["ProdID"].'">'.$data2["ProdName"].'</option>';
    }
    echo'</select></th>';
    echo '<th><input type="button" data-old="'.$data['OLDID'].'"data-id="'.$data['id'].'" value="ok" class="button"/></th>';
}
```

Вот мой ajax-обработчик:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    var oldid=$(this).data("old");
    var ProdID=$("#ProdID").val();//Данные из выпадающего списка
    jQuery.post('insert.php, { id:id , oldid:oldid , ProdID:ProdID},
        function(data) {
            alert(ProdID);
        }
    );
});
});
```

Да знаю что нужно делать это через class но не знаю как передать параметр. Точнее знаю, но знаю только передачу параметров из кнопки по её нажатию.

Comment: PS. Данные передаются, но только в переменную попадает самое первое значение ProdID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в переменную `ProdID` попадает значение первого найденного элемента с ID `#ProdID`

это должно помочь

```
foreach ($sql as $data){
    echo '<th><select id="ProdID_'.$data['id'].'">';
    foreach ($sql2 as $data2){
        echo '<option value="'.$data2["ProdID"].'">'.$data2["ProdName"].'</option>';
    }
    echo'</select></th>';
    echo '<th><input type="button" data-old="'.$data['OLDID'].'"data-id="'.$data['id'].'" value="ok" class="button"/></th>';
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    var oldid=$(this).data("old");
    var ProdID=$("#ProdID_"+$(this).data('id')).val();//Данные из выпадающего списка
    jQuery.post('insert.php, { id:id , oldid:oldid , ProdID:ProdID},
        function(data) {
            alert(ProdID);
        }
    );
});
});
```

Comment: теперь передаются данные из первого значения выпадающего списка, то есть если в выпадающем списке есть значения (1,2,3), то передаст только 1.

Comment: @user209681 не углядел. ID должно присваиваеться элементу SELECT, а не OPTION

Comment: да, работает. спасибо большое, а я ajax полный ноль(

Comment: @user209681 не забудьте принять ответ